# Problem running 'react native/expo project'

Tags: iphone, reactjs, expo

Here is the error that I am getting on my MacBook.

ERROR
11:54
jest-haste-map: Watchman crawl failed. Retrying once with node crawler.
  Usually this happens when watchman isn't running. Create an empty `.watchmanconfig` file in your project's root folder or initialize a git or hg repository in your project.

Could anyone please help? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to create the empty .watchmanconfig ?

Comment: yes, the empty .watchmanconfig was created. what is suppose to be inside of that file?